# How to remove multiple click event of javafx button

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a sample fx application with fxml using the scene buidler.
I have mapped an action handler on scene builder and write it on the java controller class. By clicking proceed button the screen will change to another screen. But sometime screen will get stuck at that time user will click proceed button multiple time, so the system will crash.

I have added disable property of button at the beginning of action controller, but it is not happening. How to block multiple event click event or just disable button at once clicked?

```
@FXML
    public void onBtnProceedClick() {
            btnProceed.setDisable(true);
          // other part of method.
}
```

FXML

```
<Button fx:id="btnProceed" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false"
    onAction="#onBtnProceedClick" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="-1.0"
    styleClass="btnProceed" text="" GridPane.columnIndex="1"
    GridPane.rowIndex="0"
/>
```

Comment: Please post both your controller and your fxml. This is a bit vague.

Comment: fxml for button added.

Comment: There is no reason I can see why your posted code won't work. Please post all the relevant parts of the Controller class.

Comment: actually i'm calling cash dispenser on the rest of my controller method.so the application will wait  sometime for dispensing amount.i think thats  why button disabling not working....which is window service calling.

Comment: You are blocking your GUI that way. But a quick solution is to check for the disabled state in your "// other part of method." and proceed only if disbled is false.

Comment: Without seeing you code I'm only taking a wild guess:
Try adding a new EventHandler to MousePressed and put the setDisable(true) there, it should catch it before OnAction.

Answer (score 0):

The event has a getClickCount(). You can add a check to say if getClickCount() > 1 then do nothing and return.